# I can't create new questions on SO

Tags: support

Every time I click on submit I get the following:

[image]

I works on meta though

Update: same happens with  ie7

[image]

I'm behind a proxy, but I don't understand why it only happens on that site, and not here on meta.

Comment: No repro on my side, are you still having this problem ?

Comment: Yeap, for a long time now :(

Comment: Did you try it with some other browser?

Comment: Or clearing your current browser's cache?

Comment: What does "More information on this error" say?

Comment: @balpha: `Below is the original error message`

`Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.`

Comment: Is this on your home network or at work?  Perhaps there is a filter in place that is acting badly?

Comment: That's at work. Looks like only that url is banned or something, because I can post on the other sites, and provide new answers ( and edit existing )  :-/

Comment: Ah - I'm getting `connection reset` errors quite frequently but only from my home PC. Work is fine. I had assumed it was a problem with my ISP.

Comment: I've found the problem... using &lt;script tag in post breaks SO server-side- markdown some how, this is the intended question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098511/how-does-the-browser-knows-how-to-interpret-the-script-tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using html's script tag breaks SO-serverside markdown somehow:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80431/using-htmls-script-tag-breaks-so-serverside-markdown-somehow)