# Using html's script tag breaks SO-serverside markdown somehow:

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I tried to create a question yesterday and I could't

I created the following here on meta:

[I can't create new questions on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80252/i-cant-create-new-questions-on-so)

After a while ( a day actually ) I *think* I figured out what happened, my question included the script tag seems to break the connection somehow.

This is the intended original question ( I used `<pre>` and `&lt;` instead... )

[image]

[How does the browser knows how to interpret the script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098511/how-does-the-browser-knows-how-to-interpret-the-script-tag)

Comment: No repo when I submitted an edit to your question.

Comment: :-/ What about creating a new one...

Comment: Perhaps is my proxy ... who knows

Comment: mmhh that's odd same happens when I add <script src="coffee-script.js"></script> <script type="text/coffeescript">alert "Hello Coffeescript!"</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this (see my above comment)

Comment: I think my work proxy process the script tag :-S Now I'm afraid. Tried at home without problem. Thanks